# Qt keyPressEvent stops working when passing parent to the class

Tags: c++, qt

I am writing a keyboard tester, so I start a dialog with

```
keybDialog keyboardTestWindow;
keyboardTestWindow.setWindowTitle("Keyboard test");
keyboardTestWindow.exec();
```

override the `keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)` and the test works superb. Now, I needed use of some parameters from parent, so instead I did

```
keybDialog keyboardTestWindow(m_parent);
keyboardTestWindow.setWindowTitle("Keyboard test");
keyboardTestWindow.exec();
```

and implemented what I needed. Now I discovered that just by instantiating the class and passing the parent to it, my dialog no longer receives the `keyPressEvent`. Are these passed to `m_parent` in some way? How can I avoid this?

EDIT:
The beginning of my `keyPressEvent`:

```
void keybDialog::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
ui->txtBxKeyboardInput->clear();
qDebug() << "Event: " << hex << event->key() << event->nativeVirtualKey() << event->modifiers() << event->nativeModifiers() << event->nativeScanCode();
ui->txtBxKeyboardInput->setText(ui->txtBxKeyboardInput->text()+event->text());

switch(sequenceNumber)
{
case 0: // Left Shift + R
    if( (event->key() == Qt::Key_R) && event->modifiers() == Qt::ShiftModifier && event->nativeModifiers() == 0x201)
    {
        reportSuccessfullKey(sequenceNumber);
    }
    else
    {
        ui->lblStatus->setText("WRONG");
    }
break;
```

Comment: What kind of key events (press vs. release, key code) are you intercepting? Is the dialog modal or not?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I added some information. I guess it is modal?